# How to shift a string's Range?

Tags: swift

I have the `Range` of a word and its enclosing sentence within a big long `String`. After extracting that sentence into its own `String`, I'd like to know the position of the word within it.

If we were dealing with integer indexes, I would just subtract the sentence's starting index from the word's range and I'd be done. For example, if the word was in characters 10–12 and its sentence started at character 8, then I'd have a new word range of 2–4.

Here's what I've got, ready to copy&paste to a Playground:

```
// The Setup (this is just to get easy testing values, no need for feedback on this part)
let bigLongString = "A beginning is the time for taking the most delicate care that the balances are correct. This every sister of the Bene Gesserit knows."
let sentenceInString = bigLongString.range(of: "This every sister of the Bene Gesserit knows.")!
let wordInString = bigLongString.range(of: "sister")!
let sentence = String(bigLongString[sentenceInString])

// The Code In Question
let wordInSentence = ??? // Something that shifts the `wordInString` range 

// The Test (again, just for testing. it should read "This every *sister* of the Bene Gesserit knows.")
print(sentence.replacingCharacters(in: wordInSentence,
                                   with: "*\(sentence[wordInSentence])*"))
```

Also, note that `wordInString` may refer to any instance of a given word, not just the first one. (So, re-finding the word in `sentence`, i.e., `sentence.range(of: "sister")`, won't do the trick here unfortunately.) The range needs to be shifted somehow.

Thanks for reading!

EDIT:
Introducing a slightly more complicated `bigLongString` seems to be an issue with the solution I posted. E.g.,

```
let bigLongString = "Really…? Thought I had it."
let sentenceInString = bigLongString.range(of: "Thought I had it.")!
let wordInString = bigLongString.range(of: "I")!
```

Comment: I also asked about this in the Swift forums for you, BTW https://forums.swift.org/t/is-there-a-safe-way-to-shift-range-string-index/35427?u=alexanderm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can get kinda tricky, depending on precisely what you need to do.

### NSRange

Firstly, as you may have noticed, `Range<String.Index>` and `NSRange` are different.

`Range<String.Index>` is how Swift represent ranges of indices in native `Swift.String`s. It's an opaque type, that's only usable by the String APIs that consume it. It understands Swift strings as collections of `Swift.Character`s, which represent what Unicode calls "extended grapheme clusters".

`NSRange` is the older range representation, used by Objective C to represent ranges in `Foundation.NSStrings`. It's an open container, containing a "start" `location` and a `length`. Importantly, these `NSRange` and `NSString` understand collections of utf16 encoded unicode scalars.

Because `NSRange` and `NSString` expose so many of their internals, they haven't undergone the same migration from utf16 to utf8 that `Swift.String` underwent. A migration that most people probably didn't even notice, since `Swift.String` guarded its implementation details much more than `NSString` did.

`NSRange` is more amenable to the kinds of simple operations you might be looking for. You can offset the start `location` just like you describe. However, you need to be careful that the resulting range doesn't start/end in the middle of an extended grapheme cluster. In that case, slicing could lead to a substring with invalid unicode characters (for example, you might accidentally cut an `e` away from its accent. the accent modifier isn't valid on its own without the `e`.)

Bridging back and forth between `NSRange` and `Range<String.Index>` is possible, but can be error prone if you're not careful. For that reason, I suggest you try to minimize conversions, by trying to either exclusively use `NSRange`, or `Range<String.Index>`, but not mix the two too much.

### `replacingCharacters(in:with:)`

I suspect you're only using this as example way of consuming `wordInSentence`, but it's still worth noting that:

`Foundation.NSString.replacingCharacters(in:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412937-replacingoccurrences) is an `NSString` API that's imported onto `Swift.String` when `Foundation` is imported. It accept an `NSString`. If you're dealing with `Range<String.Index>`, you should use its Swift-native counterpart, [`Swift.String.replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1641462-replacesubrange).

### `Substring` is your friend

Don't fight it; unless you absolutely need `sentence` to be a `String`, keep it as a `Substring` for the duration of these short-lived processing actions. Not only does this save you a copy of the string's contents, but it also makes it so that the indices can be shared between the slice and the parent string. This is valid:

```
let sentence = bigLongString[sentenceInString]
print(sentence[wordInString])
```

or even just: `bigLongString[sentenceInString][wordInString]` or `bigLongString[wordInString]`

### Shifting around

I couldn't find a native solution for this, so I rolled my own. I could definitely be missing something simpler, but here's what I came up with:

```
import Foundation

struct SubstringOffset {
    let offset: String.IndexDistance
    let parent: String

    init(of substring: Substring, in parent: String) {
        self.offset = parent.distance(from: parent.startIndex, to: substring.startIndex)
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func convert(indexInParent: String.Index, toIndexIn newString: String) -> String.Index {
        let distance = parent.distance(from: parent.startIndex, to: indexInParent)
        let distanceInNewString = distance - offset
        return newString.index(newString.startIndex, offsetBy: distanceInNewString)
    }

    func convert(rangeInParent: Range<String.Index>, toRangeIn newString: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let newLowerBound = self.convert(indexInParent: rangeInParent.lowerBound, toIndexIn: newString)

        let span = self.parent.distance(from: rangeInParent.lowerBound, to: rangeInParent.upperBound)
        let newUpperBound = newString.index(newLowerBound, offsetBy: span)

        return newLowerBound ..< newUpperBound
    }
}

// The Setup (this is just to get easy testing values, no need for feedback on this part)
let bigLongString = "Really…? Thought I had it."
let sentenceInString = bigLongString.range(of: "Thought I had it.")!
let wordInString = bigLongString.range(of: "I")!
var sentence: String = String(bigLongString[sentenceInString])

let offset = SubstringOffset(of: bigLongString[sentenceInString], in: bigLongString)
// The Code In Question
let wordInSentence: Range<String.Index> = offset.convert(rangeInParent: wordInString, toRangeIn: sentence)

sentence.replaceSubrange(wordInSentence, with: "*\(sentence[wordInSentence])*")
print(sentence)
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. In this case, the extracted `sentence` objects will live on long after `bigLongString` so they can't be `Substrings`, unfortunately!

Comment: @Rogare Ah, good on your for knowing that. That's a lesser-known kind of memory leak.

Comment: Check out my edit. IDK if I'm missing a simpler way, but I cracked it

Comment: Yup, it works! It could also simply be `RangeOffset` with the first `init` parameter as `String.Index`. For really big `bigLongString`s, the `distance(from: parent.startIndex, to: indexInParent)` call might be expensive if it's O(n), so tweaking it to use the distance calls in my answer may help. But yeah, thanks for the detailed and working answer!

Comment: Yeah, i just wanted to tuck away as much of the range/index cruft as possible, so i took the slice even though i didn't need it. In any case, I don't think there's a way to escape the O(n)ness here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what I've come up with. It appears to work OK for both examples in the question.

We use the `String` instance method `distance(from:to:)` to get the distance between the `bigLongString` start and the `sentence` start. (Analogous to the "8" in the question.) Then the word range is shifted back by this amount by shifting the upper and lower bounds separately, and then reforming them into a `Range`.

```
let wordStartInSentence = bigLongString.distance(from: sentenceInString.lowerBound,
                                                 to: wordInString.lowerBound)
let wordEndInSentence = bigLongString.distance(from: sentenceInString.lowerBound,
                                               to: wordInString.upperBound)
let wordStart = sentence.index(sentence.startIndex, offsetBy: wordStartInSentence)
let wordEnd = sentence.index(sentence.startIndex, offsetBy: wordEndInSentence)
let wordInSentence = wordStart..<wordEnd
```

EDIT: Updated answer to work for the more complicated `bigLongString` example (and coincidentally also reduce the "string walking," especially when `bigLongString` is very big).

Comment: Pretty good. Two things: 1) remember that `distance(from:to:)` is `O(n)` (because it has to walk the string and do cluster breaking as it counts), so if you need to do this a lot, it's better to convert to a `[Character]` and back 2) this would be nicer in an extension to `Range`. I'm giving that a shot.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Great points. I think the updated answer addresses the first point, but agreed that an extension would be much nicer to look at!